# How to exclude null values when using DECODE in SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE e_table 
(
 e_id        NUMBER(10),
 q_id        NUMBER(10),
 a_value     VARCHAR2(20),
 r_pos_a_id  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 13, null   , null );
INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 15, null   , null );
INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 14, null   , null );
INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 16, null   , null );
INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 13, null   , 992  );
INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 13, null   , 637  );
INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 15, null   , 637  );
INSERT INTO e_table VALUES( 11, 14,'Manual', null );

SELECT e_id,
       SUM(decode(q_id, 13, 1, 0)) src_cnt,
       SUM(decode(q_id, 15, 1, 0)) tgt_cnt,
       SUM(decode(q_id, 14, 1, 0)) src_oth,
       SUM(decode(q_id, 16, 1, 0)) tgt_oth
  FROM e_table
 GROUP BY e_id;
```

Expected output:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| E_ID   | SRC_CNT   | TGT_CNT   | SRC_OTH  |  TGT_OTH |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     11 |         2 |         1 |        1 |        0 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Currently, I am doing the sum for all the occurrences of q_id in the table. Say for `q_id` 13 it's coming as 3 times in the table `e_table` and likewise for all the `q_id` i.e 14, 15, and 16. But I want to exclude the null values. If `a_value` and `r_pos_a_id`are null for that particular id then I have to exclude that entry from my occurrences count. For instance, `q_id` 13 is coming as thrice but it should count only for the ones which have either `a_value` or `r_pos_a_id` and exclude that has both `a_value` and `r_pos_a_id` as null. And the same I have to do for all the q_id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some more *conditions* into `CASE`. Why `CASE` and not `DECODE`? Because it allows *flexibility*.

```
SQL> select e_id,
  2    sum(case when q_id = 13 and (a_value is not null or r_pos_a_id is not null) then 1 else 0 end) src_cnt,
  3    sum(case when q_id = 15 and (a_value is not null or r_pos_a_id is not null) then 1 else 0 end) tgt_cnt,
  4    sum(case when q_id = 14 and (a_value is not null or r_pos_a_id is not null) then 1 else 0 end) src_oth,
  5    sum(case when q_id = 16 and (a_value is not null or r_pos_a_id is not null) then 1 else 0 end) tgt_oth
  6  from e_table
  7  group by e_id;

      E_ID    SRC_CNT    TGT_CNT    SRC_OTH    TGT_OTH
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        11          2          1          1          0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet you can use `DECODE` through connecting with `SIGN` and `NVL2`, *which lets you substitution of both a null and as well as a non-null value*, functions combination such as

```sql
SELECT e_id,
       SUM(DECODE(q_id, 13, SIGN(NVL2(a_value,1,0)+NVL2(r_pos_a_id,1,0)))) AS src_cnt,
       SUM(DECODE(q_id, 15, SIGN(NVL2(a_value,1,0)+NVL2(r_pos_a_id,1,0)))) AS tgt_cnt,
       SUM(DECODE(q_id, 14, SIGN(NVL2(a_value,1,0)+NVL2(r_pos_a_id,1,0)))) AS src_oth,
       SUM(DECODE(q_id, 16, SIGN(NVL2(a_value,1,0)+NVL2(r_pos_a_id,1,0)))) AS tgt_oth
  FROM e_table
 GROUP BY e_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c731082553e665144fdfeb5be03d843)</kbd>

where if `a_value` or `r_pos_a_id` are non-null, then `NVL2` function would return 1 , otherwise would return 0 respectively. There would be no problem (the total value would be 0 or 1) unless both are non-null. In this case, the `SIGN` function is used in order to count each non-null combination once.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution but how this will work could you please explain in short? I could see 1 and 0 written for both bolumns a_value and r_pos_a_id

Comment: you're welcome @Vicky , I've just added an explanation, good luck.